# Why this regular expression is not working in PHP but works in .net?

Tags: php, regex

Below is a regex which works fine in .net but give me error if I use it in PHP.

```
(?<=")([^"]+,[^"]+)?(?=")
```

What does this regex is supposed to return?

Input: `1,"x1",43,"tr","y,7"`

It will return me `"y,7"` in this case. In general, it will return any part between `"` and `"` if it has a comma between it.

When I try to use this in PHP, I get following error:

> Unknown modifier '('

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~(?<=")([^"]+,[^"]+)?(?=")~
```

For php (`preg_*` functions) you need to specify delimiter around the regex iteself. It can be `!`, `/`, `#`, `~`, etc.

Comment: Can be even `(...)`. That is why PHP throws this error, it thinks the expression is `(?<=")` and the following `(` is not a valid modifier.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 1,"x1",43,"tr","
    [1] => "
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1,"x1",43,"tr","
    [1] => "
)


I need "y,7" in result.

Comment: @Mihir: debug it, then. Rewrite it from the scratch.

Comment: @Mihir: Works fine for me: `preg_match_all('~(?<=")([^"]+,[^"]+)?(?=")~','1,"x1",43,"tr","y,7"', $a);` You might want the first character group match non-greedy: `[^"]+?` or add `,` to it.